# Convert double to string keeping high precision of the digits, C++

Tags: c++, string, double, decimal

I have been trying to convert a double into string without the C++11 (ToString) but it only accepts the number of decimals to be 5 as default. How can I change that?

The command is:

```
    string a = static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream()<<digits) )->str();
```

but it keeps 5 decimals while I want to create a string which has all the decimals (e.g. 100)
I know that, that many decimals dont matter. This is one point of the exercise I was doing.

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much for your time
Cheers!

Comment: You shuold read [goldberg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), then reconsider your question, once you have decided how many meaningful *decimal* digits can be extracted from your (*binary*) `double`.

Comment: _"all the decimals (e.g. 100)"_ lolwut

Answer (score 5):

Use IO manipulators [setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/) here on `std::cout` but works on `stringstream`:

```
// setprecision example from cplusplus.com
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::fixed
#include <iomanip>      // std::setprecision

int main () {
  double f =3.14159;
  std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(9) << f << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

By the way, no `double` will have 100 meaningfull digit, it's 15 or 17, I forgot exactly how many.

EDIT: I forgot, if you can use C++11... You can (and should) use [to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

```
#include <string>

// ....    
std::string f_str = std::to_string(f);
```

Comment: thank you Johan, you are right about the many digits that they have no use, so lets see about putting 15 digits to a string

Comment: I explicitly said I cannot use C++11..... so how can this be done with a stringstream

Comment: @thahgr: The answer already tells you to use the I/O manipulators on your `std::stringstream` just as demonstrated on `std::cout`.

Comment: The closest I can get is

        double digits = 12.1234512345;

        string a;          

        stringstream ss;   

        ss << fixed<<setprecision(10)<<digits; 

        a = ss.str(); 


but I get" ‘setprecision’ was not declared in this scope"


all this is part of a function I have in a class, is that the reason I get the error message?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me finally

```
      digits = 1.12345123451234;
      char buff[100];
      sprintf(buff, "%1.14f", digits);
      string a(buff);
```

Thanks for checking it in any case

Cheers

Comment: Why do you allocate so much buffer?